# Issue populating child collections using MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
const MenuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  children: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Menu' }],
});
```

And the following query:

```
    const item = await Menu.findOne({ _id: <id> }).populate({
        path: 'children',
    });
    console.log(item.children);
```

I'm attempting to recursively populate the child array with the actual related documents, I can populate the first collection, but I need to do that recursively effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do

```js
 const item = await Menu.findOne({ _id: <id> }).populate('children');
 console.log(item.children);
```

.populate takes the path as the first parameter, no need to put in an object